# Proofs from the book: in Praise of inequality's

Tags: calculus

I am reading a book with nice proofs, but i struggle at a few points.

1) why is

$\sum_{i=1}^{k} p_i \int_{a_i}^{G} (\frac{1}{t} - \frac{1}{G}) dt + \sum_{i=k+1}^{n} p_i \int_{G}^{a_i} (\frac{1}{G} - \frac{1}{t}) dt \geq 0$

the same as

$\sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i \int_{G}^{a_i} \frac{1}{G} dt \geq \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i \int_{G}^{a_i} \frac{1}{t}$

i got the feeling it's quite trivial but i don't seem to see it. The other point is a proof of another theorem with graphs so i'm going to post that in another question.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure that the second summation isn’t $$\sum_{i=k+1}^np_i\int_G^{a_i}\left(\frac1G-\frac1t\right)dt\;?$$

Comment: you're right, i made a typo. I still don't see it though

Comment: what is the name and the author of this book?

Comment: Gunter M ziegler

Comment: i think i see the solution, i feel stupid now -_- i forget to the minus when changing bounds....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\int_{a_i}^G\left(\frac1t-\frac1G\right)dt=\int_G^{a_i}\left(\frac1G-\frac1t\right)dt\;,$$

so the first inequality is equivalent to

$$\sum_{i=1}^kp_i\int_G^{a_i}\left(\frac1G-\frac1t\right)dt+\sum_{i=k+1}^np_i\int_G^{a_i}\left(\frac1G-\frac1t\right)dt\ge 0\;.\tag{1}$$

The summations on the lefthand side of $(1)$ have identical summands, so they can be combined, making the inequality

$$\sum_{i=1}^np_i\int_G^{a_i}\left(\frac1G-\frac1t\right)dt\ge 0\;.$$

Now just split the lefthand side:

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^np_i\int_G^{a_i}\left(\frac1G-\frac1t\right)dt&=\sum_{i=1}^n\left(p_i\int_G^{a_i}\frac1G\,dt-p_i\int_G^{a_i}\frac1t\,dt\right)\\
&=\sum_{i=1}^np_i\int_G^{a_i}\frac1G\,dt-\sum_{i=1}^np_i\int_G^{a_i}\frac1t\,dt
\end{align*}$$

and transpose the second term.

Comment: thanks dude appreciate it!

Comment: @Kees: You’re welcome!